# Disassociate InfoPath Form with SharePoint List

Tags: infopath

So, I created a SharePoint List and spent a fair amount of time customizing the form in InfoPath adding various bits of functionality (via SharePoint Site-->List Settings-->Customize Form).  Eventually I ran into a few features that are disabled in InfoPath when you edit the SharePoint List form (things like repeating fields).  I'm searching for a way to disassociate or disconnect the InfoPath form from the SharePoint List without recreating the form from scratch.  Ideally I'd like the form to function as if I created it from scratch without the association to the SharePoint List.

At the moment I'm sifting through the source files trying to manually remove the references and not really having much luck.

Anyone have any thoughts, new ideas or past experiences?

Answer (score 9):

Go to **List Settings**. In the **General Settings** section, pick **Form Settings**. You can then pick to use either the InfoPath form or the default SharePoint form, and optionally delete the InfoPath form if so desired.

Comment: This worked although it prompted that Internet Explorer was required to access Form Settings

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint Designer open the list and in the Forms Section, right click the default form for the operation (Edit, Display, New) and select (I believe the verbiage is) "use as default".

Comment: Thanks for the input but I'm not looking to reset the form back to the default Edit/Display/New.  I'm looking for a way to turn the InfoPath form that SharePoint created for the List into an independent InfoPath form that can be reused through that the rest of SharePoint.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not understand that from my first reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind to loose all your functionality (rules, code) then the simplest way is just to open the old form in Infopath Designer 2010 (which type in case of "Sharepoint List Form", select all on Design surface CTRL+A, CTRL+C and copy-paste CTRL+A, CTRL+V into another instance of IPD2010 with manually created Infopath form.

AFAIU, you cannot do much more or easy since any element (or component) created in unmodifiable "Sharepoint List Form" type of Infopath form is hard-coded under **"SharePointListItem_RW"**  and other variations of **SharePointList** substring.

You can export source file (in IPD2010, File > Publish > Export Source File or by renaming the extension of template from .xsn to .cab > right-click on file > Extract  ) and in text/XML editor to check the amount of files additionally generated in comparison to modifiable types of IP forms and amount of "SharePointList" subtrings in them. There are practically no parts non-infected "SharePointList" subtring there.